# Cartoon with arrogant adventurer, sympathetic sidekick

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

There was this American or Canadian 90s-looking cartoon, with a blustery adventurer that had a chin as big as his ego, who always took all the credit when his much smarter, skinnier sidekick did the actual work.

One particular episode involved a *Sleeping Beauty*-style quest for a princess sleeping in a tower/castle, who had to be awoken with a kiss. When they finally find her lying on a stone slab, the adventurer leans in to kiss her, but the sidekick glances into a mirror and realizes in horror that the girl has no reflection, and the adventurer is about to be bitten by a vampire lying in wait.

After saving him and killing the vampire, a large slot in the wall opens up and a second stone slab is pushed out on top of the first one, with the real sleeping princess lying on it.

*Edit: Apparently this last part is a different show entirely:* At the end of an episode, the adventurer is disgusted by a disappointingly worthless reward of some kind, and discards the reward with the sidekick and begins to ride off, abandoning him. The sidekick then notices something the adventurer missed, realizes he actually has a fortune in his hands, and starts laughing uncontrollably. The oblivious adventurer confidently continues stating that nothing sidekick says is going to make him turn around, as he rides away slowly, which sidekick is all too happy with.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d3daV3_uXW4?

Comment: Looks like a match. https://youtu.be/d3daV3_uXW4?t=15m36s

Comment: If the second part is a different Story-ID, edit it out and create a new question

Answer (score 7):

Could this be the [Tales from the Cryptkeeper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tales_from_the_Cryptkeeper) episode *Sleeping Beauty*?

It features a hero with a jaw that you could crack rocks on, a weaselly sidekick and a sleeping beauty who turns out to be a vamp.